# Android: How to change the Android core of the project

Tags: android, maps

Recently I started to dev on Android programe developed by some other guy who left the company. He started the project as non Google API project and now there is a requirement to use the GPS & Google maps.

Since he started as non Google API project, I couldn't use them. Is there any way to change this?? if so Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Eclipse, right click the project folder in package explorer, hit properties, and select Android. A list of available build targets will appear.

Answer (score 2):

alright... most probably you are using Eclipse..
Right click on Project---> Properties----->Select android-----> Select Project Build Target

Comment: You can also select the api level there